# Conditional Split arrays within a cell

Tags: matlab

Assume I have a 50x1 cell(say Q) with column matrices of varying dimensions (say 1568936x1 , 88x1,5040x1 ) etc
losing values isn't an issue. I need all the matrices inside the cell to be divisible by said number (say 500) so like 1568500x1 , 5000x1 skipping  over 88x1 etc.

Currently I have:

```
z=cell(length(Q),1)

for p=1:length(z)
    n=length(Q{p})
    for w=1:length(z)
        if n-mod(length(Q{w}),500)<500
            w=w+1;
        else
            o=length(Q{w}-mod(length(Q{w}),500));
            for k=1:length(z)
                z=Q{w}((1:o));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

but when I reach the 88x1 matrix it throws a dimensions exceeded error although I think I have covered that with the if condition where it should skip the matrix and move on to the next cell.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do but I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be modifying the loop variable `w` inside the loop. If you want to skip the code inside the loop when a certain condition is met then just place that code after the `if` statement (no `else` is needed) and rewrite your `if` expression so that it is only true when that condition is false.

Comment: Thanks for answering and making my code pretty. I basically need it to take uniformly divisible values and skip matrices in the cell which are smaller than the number (like 500) . The `else` does seem unnecessary and it was kind of a sanity check but I'll try out and update soon.

Comment: So are you trying to end up with a cell array `z` which contains the data from `Q` but each vector is truncated to a size which is a multiple of 500, or omitted altogether if it is shorter than 500?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly correct. I have also just noticed that I am getting a row matrix output for a column matrix input so I probably need to fix that too as it should be the same structure as the initial cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
Q = {
   rand(58,1);
   rand(168,1);
   rand(33,1);
   rand(199,1);
   rand(100,1)
};

Q_len = numel(Q);

K = 50;
Z = cell(Q_len,1);

for i = 1:Q_len
    Qi = Q{i};
    Qi_len = numel(Qi);

    k = floor(Qi_len / K) * K

    Z{i} = Qi(1:k);
end
```

Given the starting vectors (shortened down in order to avoid excessive overloads), the final output `Z` is:

```
>> cellfun(@numel,Z)

ans =
    50
   150
     0
   150
   100
```

If you want a shorter, one-liner version, here is one:

```
Q = {
   rand(58,1);
   rand(168,1);
   rand(33,1);
   rand(199,1);
   rand(100,1)
};

K = 50;
Z = cellfun(@(x)x(1:(floor(numel(x)/K)*K)),Q,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! . It works perfectly for column matrices. So ,Slightly off topic but I've tried this  for a matrices with fixed number of columns greater than 1 and it's pushing values to the next highest multiple (say a 75798x10 matrix to 76000x10 when I need it to give me 75500x10) which is odd seeing `floor` usage and some of the matrices returned do not even follow this pattern and seem off to me. This works for my original question however so thank you so much.

Comment: For matrices you should apply a two-dimensional indexing, if you provide an example I can edit my answer.

Comment: By the way, the rounding problem looks really really weird to me. 75798 / 500 = 151.596, which is floored down to 151. 151 * 500 = 75.500. This shouldn't fail at all.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo surely for a 75798x10 matrix `numel` is 757980, dividing by 500 gives 1515.96, rounded ends up at 757500. I'm not sure where David is getting 76000x10 from but it's clear why it's not 75500x10.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo I'm not sure myself honestly . Perhaps it has to do with the column dimensions . As for an example I think I mentioned how it should ignore the column values which are uniform and only truncate the rows according to the suitable multiple of choice. Edit: It's giving me a raised value  due to it taking the column matrices (for example: a 192503x13 matrix returned a 1x2502000. It'll be a more acceptable number after 2d indexing (my fault I should've done it)  but as pointed out by nekomatic above I will not get my expected answer .

Comment: However I got the gist of it and I'm pretty confident I can make it work so thanks again!